# How can I append html after the last list element that has a specific class?

Tags: jquery

I have three unordered lists on my page. Each unordered list item has a class of "foo":

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

I am pretty sure I need to use `last-child` since I want the last item in *each* unordered list. However what I have tried so far either puts three `<hr>` elements at the last unordered list or I get one line under the first or the second. The obvious just hasn't hit me yet - any suggestions would be appreciated.

**jquery**

```
$('li.foo:last-child').after('<hr>');

$('ul').each(function(){
    $('<hr>').insertAfter('li.foo');
});
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <hr>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <hr>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <hr>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you to @Azim for the suggestion. For anyone who may come across this thread, to take it a step further if you want to insert markup (or do whatever) to all elements unless it *is* the last element you can do this:

**jquery**

```
$('ul').each(function () {
    $(this).find('li.foo').not(':last-child').after('<hr>');
});
```

That will yield something like this:

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <hr>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
    <li class="foo">item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate through each `ul` and find the last `li` having class `foo` and add `<hr>` after that like below.

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    $(this).find('li.foo:last').after('<hr>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    $('<hr>').insertAfter($(this).find('li.foo:last'));
});
```

Iterate through each **ul** and find the **last li**. Insert `<hr>` after the last **li**

**Important Note**:

One major difference is the "**return**" value. The instance whose function you call is the instance will be returned.

In my mentioned answer you will get the instance of `<hr>` element where as if you use `after`

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    $(this).find('li.foo:last').after('<hr>');
});
```

This will give you the `li.foo:last` element as return value which will help further chaining of function.

Answer (score 0):

The following will call the function for each `ul` and then insert the `<hr>` after the last foo below it:

```
$("ul").each(function () {
    $('<hr>').insertAfter($(this).find(".foo").last());
});
```